# Reading a PGM file using structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-arrays, pgm

I am doing a project that involves writing functions to read/write and encode/decode PGM files. Im using a structure with a function to read in the PGM file. I am quite new to structures and how they are syntaxed so I am just wondering if this bit of code would correctly read in the scanned data into my structure.

Here is my code (C):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "image.h"

int **allocatePGM(int numCols, int numRows){
        int ** = malloc(sizeof(int *) * numRows);
        for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++)
            pixels[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * numCols);
        return pixels;

}

ImagePGM *readPGM(char *filename, ImagePGM *pImagePGM){
    FILE *inFile = NULL
    char PGMcheck[5];
    int max_value = 0;
    unsigned int width = 0, height = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    int pixeldata = 0;




    inFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    printf("File could not be opened\n");
    exit(1);

fgets(PGMcheck, sizeof(PGMcheck), inFile);
if (strcmp(version, "P5")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong file type!\n");
    exit(1);
}
    printf("This file does not contain the PGM indicator \"P2\"");
    exit(1);
    }




    fscanf(inFile, "%d", &width);
    fscanf(inFile, "%d", &height);
    fscanf(inFile, "%d", max_value);

    struct ImagePGM.pImagePGM
    pImagePGM.magic = PGMcheck;
    pImagePGM.width = width;
    pImagePGM.height = height;
    pImagePGM.max_value = max_value;

    pImagePGM->pixels = allocatePGM(pImagePGM->width, pImagePGM->height);
    if (pImagePGM->max_value > 255) {
        for (i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
                pImagePGM->pixels[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return pImagePGM;

}
```

My header file contains the structure as follows...

```
typedef struct _imagePGM {
 char magic[3]; // magic identifier, "P2" for PGM
 int width; // number of columns
 int height; // number of rows
 int max_value; // maximum grayscale intensity
 int **pixels; // the actual grayscale pixel data, a 2D array
} ImagePGM;
```

Seem okay to you guys?

Comment: The `max_value` (by current specification) must be < 65536, so your `pixels` need only be either 8-bit or 16-bit integers.  If space is an issue, you may want to change that.  It's always a toss-up whether to allocate a 2D array, or just a 1D array, and use the `width` to traverse it.  But typically I use a 1D array + known-width if I can - it just makes the code simpler.  For example, this allows the code to just `fread()` and `fwrite()` of the whole pixel-data block (assuming exact size pixel-storage)

Comment: Huh? `"P2" (plain format)`? See [pgm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html). What makes you think `fscanf(inFile, "%s", PGMcheck);` will read only 2-characters? There are a large number of similar errors. Further, you can't compare strings with equality operators (e.g. you can't `PGMcheck != "P2"`)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the official NetPBM libraries for reading and writing these files?  Those libraries are quite easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my earlier comment, you have several problems that have to do with handling the [Plain PGM File Format](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html) that will prevent your successful read of the file.

First, `fgets(PGMcheck, sizeof(PGMcheck), inFile);` is not guaranteed to read `PGMcheck` correctly. The *magic-number* may be followed by `"(blanks, TABs, CRs, LFs)"` so `fgets` will read more than just the *magic-number* unless it is followed by a single `'\n'` -- not guaranteed by the format. While `fgets()` is generally the correct way to do line-oriented input, the PGM format isn't guaranteed to be formatted in lines, so you are left using a *formatted-input* function, or a character-by-character approach.

(you can use `fgets()`, but that would require parsing the resulting buffer and saving whatever part of the buffer extended beyond the *magic-number* to include as the beginning part of your next read)

You have corrected your attempt at the string comparison using `!=` instead of `strcmp`, but you still must compare the *magic-number* with `"P2"` for reading a Plain-PGM format file (as your question included originally) Go ahead and read the *magic-number* into a string, but use a formatted-input function (`fscanf`) to read only up until the first whitespace is encountered, regardless of what that whitespace is.

Lastly, there is no need to store the *magic-number* as part of the `plain_pgm` struct. That is something your *validate* before you attempt to fill the struct. It either is `"P2"` or it isn't -- no need to store it.

For portability, it is a good idea to use *exact-width* types for storage when reading image files. There are a number of benefits, but the primary being, your program will behave correctly whether run on your x86_64 or on your TI-MSP432 chip. The exact width types are defined in `stdint.h` and the macros from printing and reading the exact width types are provided in `inttypes.h`. Instead of `char` you have `int8_t`, instead of `unsigned char` you have `uint8_t`, and so on, where the numeric value specifies the exact number of bytes for the type.

With that your pgm struct could look like:

```
typedef struct {            /* struct for plain pgm image */
    uint32_t w, h;          /* use exact width types for portable code */
    uint16_t max;           /* 16-bit max */
    uint16_t **pixels;      /* pointer-to-pointer for pixel values */
} plain_pgm;
```

Your allocation is largely correct, but rearranging to return a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `uint16_t` (adequate for the `maximum gray value` pixel values), you could do:

```
uint16_t **alloc_pgm_pixels (uint32_t w, uint32_t h)
{
    uint16_t **pixels = NULL;

    /* allocate/validate height number of pointers */
    if (!(pixels = malloc (h * sizeof *pixels))) {
        perror ("malloc-pixels");
        return NULL;
    }
    /* allocate/validate width number of values per-pointer */
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < h; i++)
        if (!(pixels[i] = malloc (w * sizeof *pixels[i]))) {
            perror ("malloc-pixels[i]");
            return NULL;
        }

    return pixels;  /* return allocated pointers & storage */
}
```

Your read function needs lots of help. First, you generally want to open and validate the file is open for reading in the calling function and pass the open `FILE *` pointer as a parameter to your read function rather than the filename. (if the file cannot be opened in the caller, there is no need to make the function call to begin with). With that change and passing a pointer to your struct, your read function could look like:

```
int read_pgm (FILE *fp, plain_pgm *pgm)
{
    char buf[RDBUF];            /* buffer for magic number */
    uint32_t h = 0, w = 0;      /* height/width counters */

    if (fscanf (fp, "%s", buf) != 1) {  /* read magic number */
        fputs ("error: invalid format - magic\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    if (strcmp (buf, MAGIC_PLN) != 0) { /* validate magic number */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid magic number '%s'.\n", buf);
        return 0;
    }

    /* read pgm width, height, max gray value */
    if (fscanf (fp, "%" SCNu32 " %" SCNu32 " %" SCNu16, 
                &pgm->w, &pgm->h, &pgm->max) != 3) {
        fputs ("error: invalid format, h, w, max or included comments.\n",
                stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    /* validate allocation of pointers and storage for pixel values */
    if (!(pgm->pixels = alloc_pgm_pixels (pgm->w, pgm->h)))
        return 0;

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until image read */
        if (fscanf (fp, "%" SCNu16, &pgm->pixels[h][w]) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: stream error or short-read.\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        if (++w == pgm->w)
            w = 0, h++;
        if (h == pgm->h)
            break;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

(**note:** this read function does NOT consider *comment lines*, implementing ignoring of comment lines is left to you. You could either make an additional call to `fscanf` before and between reading each part of the magic-number, width, height, and max gray value with something similar to `" # %[^\n']"` to skip any number of whitespace and read up to and including the next `'#'` character and to the end of line, or just use `fgetc` in a loop searching for the next non-whitespace character and checking if it is a `'#'` and if not use `ungetc`, if so, clear to the end of line.)

Putting it altogether in an example, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define RDBUF       32      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAGIC_PLN  "P2"

typedef struct {            /* struct for plain pgm image */
    uint32_t w, h;          /* use exact width types for portable code */
    uint16_t max;           /* 16-bit max */
    uint16_t **pixels;      /* pointer-to-pointer for pixel values */
} plain_pgm;

uint16_t **alloc_pgm_pixels (uint32_t w, uint32_t h)
{
    uint16_t **pixels = NULL;

    /* allocate/validate height number of pointers */
    if (!(pixels = malloc (h * sizeof *pixels))) {
        perror ("malloc-pixels");
        return NULL;
    }
    /* allocate/validate width number of values per-pointer */
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < h; i++)
        if (!(pixels[i] = malloc (w * sizeof *pixels[i]))) {
            perror ("malloc-pixels[i]");
            return NULL;
        }

    return pixels;  /* return allocated pointers & storage */
}

int read_pgm (FILE *fp, plain_pgm *pgm)
{
    char buf[RDBUF];            /* buffer for magic number */
    uint32_t h = 0, w = 0;      /* height/width counters */

    if (fscanf (fp, "%s", buf) != 1) {  /* read magic number */
        fputs ("error: invalid format - magic\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    if (strcmp (buf, MAGIC_PLN) != 0) { /* validate magic number */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid magic number '%s'.\n", buf);
        return 0;
    }

    /* read pgm width, height, max gray value */
    if (fscanf (fp, "%" SCNu32 " %" SCNu32 " %" SCNu16, 
                &pgm->w, &pgm->h, &pgm->max) != 3) {
        fputs ("error: invalid format, h, w, max or included comments.\n",
                stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    /* validate allocation of pointers and storage for pixel values */
    if (!(pgm->pixels = alloc_pgm_pixels (pgm->w, pgm->h)))
        return 0;

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until image read */
        if (fscanf (fp, "%" SCNu16, &pgm->pixels[h][w]) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: stream error or short-read.\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        if (++w == pgm->w)
            w = 0, h++;
        if (h == pgm->h)
            break;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    plain_pgm pgm = { .w = 0 }; /* plain_pgm struct instance */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!read_pgm (fp, &pgm)) { /* validate/allocate/read pgm file */
        fputs ("error: read_pgm failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (fp != stdin)            /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    /* output success */
    printf ("successful read of '%s'\n%" PRIu32 "x%" PRIu32 " pixel values.\n",
            argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin", pgm.w, pgm.h);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < pgm.h; i++)    /* free pixel storage */
        free (pgm.pixels[i]);
    free (pgm.pixels);                      /* free pointers */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using an example [apollonian_gasket.ascii.pgm, a 600 wide by 600 high image of an Apollonian gasket](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/pgma/apollonian_gasket.ascii.pgm) file as a test file, you would get:

```
$ ./bin/read_pgm_plain dat/apollonian_gasket.ascii.pgm
successful read of 'dat/apollonian_gasket.ascii.pgm'
600x600 pixel values.
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/read_pgm_plain dat/apollonian_gasket.ascii.pgm
==8086== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8086== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8086== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8086== Command: ./bin/read_pgm_plain dat/apollonian_gasket.ascii.pgm
==8086==
successful read of 'dat/apollonian_gasket.ascii.pgm'
600x600 pixel values.
==8086==
==8086== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8086==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8086==   total heap usage: 604 allocs, 604 frees, 730,472 bytes allocated
==8086==
==8086== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8086==
==8086== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8086== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look over the changes made and if you don't understand why something wast done, drop a comment asking and I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PGM specification, but you have three common mistakes that can make your code misbehave when compiled on platform distinct than yours:

1. Endianess. You have to precisely define it for your data format.
   In your case ints are likely little-endian, you have to account for that when porting your code to big-endian platform.
   See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness
2. Structure packing. Depending on the platform, compiler can pad fields in structs for faster access. You likely want to use construct like pragma pack for your structs, otherwise, again, your code might have issues with the other compiler (even assuming the same platform).
   See also http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_structure_alignment_and_padding
3. Use fixed width types. E.g. use int64_t instead of long, etc.
   See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Fixed-width_integer_types